Content security policy error in Vercel deployment
I have the following error when I deploy the server to vercel.

Refused to load the script 'https://vercel.live/_next-live/feedback/feedback.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback

I tried the following in index.js to solve but it does not make any effect.
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   res.setHeader(
     'Content-Security-Policy', "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' cdn.example.com https://vercel.live; img-src 'self' img.example.com; style-src 'self';"
   );
   next();
});"

